# OpenMP in Visual Studio with the Intel C++ compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, openmp, icc

I am using VS2010 and the Intel C++ compiler (Intel Composer XE 2013 SP1.) When I try to parallellize a for-loop using OpenMP I get the following warning:

```
warning #3180: unrecognized OpenMP #pragma
```

Looking at http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-openmp it seems I should pass `/Qopenmp` as a command line option, but I am not entirely sure where to do this in VS.

Where in VS do I activate OpenMP support for the Intel C++ compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click project, then go to Properties, then Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language [Intel C++] -> OpenMP Support